# How can I create a interface with a camera button like tweetbot

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, user-interface

I don't know how to create a textfield with a camera button like the one in the screenshot.

Is there any open source project that creates a user interface like that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you are approaching this in the wrong way. This, to me, looks like a UITextView (because it's multi-line) and a UIToolbar set to animate in with the keyboard when that gets called.

So, in short: UITextView for the tweet, UILabel (with perhaps a button on top) for the location, a toolbar that animates in when the keyboard gets called when the view loads and then, at least initially, a camera button, that morphs into a UIImageView with a clear button slapped on top once you initially select an image.

Answer (score 0):

Rather than use a UIToolbar, you can set an Input Accessory View on the keyboard, and this will correctly position itself regardless of what keyboard the user is using (some keyboards are higher to make room for completion options, e.g. Japanese & Chinese).

Good write up of Input Accessory View here: http://gabriel-tips.blogspot.com/2011/05/input-accessory-view-how-to-add-extra.html